# How to display month in twig file using 0-11 arguments (jQuery FullCalendar)

Tags: symfony, twig, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a query string to a link in my twig file for the purpose of jumping to today's agenda in jQuery FullCalendar, but the months are based on a 0-11 structure rather than the standard 01-12.

I am using the following string to generate the query in my twig template:

```
<a href="{{ path('app_show_calendar') }}?y={{ "now"|date("Y") }}&m={{ "now"|date_modify("-1 month")|date("m") }}&d={{ "now"|date("d") }}">View Today's Agenda</a>
```

But using the "date_modify" and "-1 month" will not work if it's January as it will render "12" instead for the previous December. So, if it's January it needs to show as "0".

Is the way of doing this in Twig? It's not practical for me to render it in my Controller PHP as I'd have to do it many times due to my extensive range of pages in my CRM.

Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
&m={{ ("now"|date("m"))-1 }}
```

Comment: Aha! Didn't realise it was that simple! Thank you